# Capacitor PushNotification Callback nor being called

Tags: capacitor

I'm using the push notification plugin on my application and the call back is not working `PushNotifications.addListener( 'registration', ( token: PushNotificationToken ) => ...`

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... there is a block of code that needs to be changed on the `AppDelegate.swift` and `Podfile` files.

**AppDelegate.swift:**
Change this:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.name()), object: deviceToken)
  }
```

for this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
          Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
          InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
              if let error = error {
                  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError.name()), object: error)
              } else if let result = result {
                  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.name()), object: result.token)
              }
          }
      }
```

**PodFile:**

Add under *capacitor_pods*:

`pod 'Firebase/Messaging'`